# i18n implementation- jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, internationalization

My website contains a lot of dynamic HTML

Currently, all the labels and tool-tip for the elements are hard-coded in .js file like below:

```
<div class="someClassName" title="Tracked item details">Name of Label</div>
```

What I want is that instead of hard coding it, I want to create file (or something similar in client side only) containing keys like we create in .properties file (server side) and use those keys to get the value of that key in js.

**Purpose:** If I want to display another message for that particular key, I just need to change the value of the key at one place only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't found the exact solution to the issue. But a solution which is working is that we can define the key value pairs for js in the properties file (server side). On logging into the application, we can perform an ajax request on document load which will return the JSON string of that properties file. Now, save that object in a js variable. And use this variable to access the property where ever needed.

```
<div class="someClassName" title="'+loadPropertyValue("tracking.name.title")+'">'+loadPropertyValue("label.name")+'</div>

function loadPropertyValue(key) {

for(var i = 0; i < propertiesObject.length; i++)
{
  var item = propertiesObject[i];
  if(item[key]) {
      return item[key];
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a js object/json object like

`var abc = {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'};`

so that you just need to update the above object and just reassign the value where u need it.

Thanks